# Sharing ASP.NET authentication cookies across apps and servers

Tags: asp.net, authentication, cookies, asp.net-core

I'm trying to share authentication cookies across a .NET Core app and an MVC 5 application. This is possible according to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/compatibility/cookie-sharing but requires the servers to have physical access to a shared directory that holds the Data Protection keys.

How does one go about sharing these keys if the servers are not physically located together? In my case they're different Azure Web Sites.

Comment: Have you tried using blob storage? https://github.com/aspnet/DataProtection/blob/rel/1.1.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.AzureStorage/AzureDataProtectionBuilderExtensions.cs#L33

Comment: That solves the issue on the ASP.NET Core side of things, but for my MVC 5 application, I don't see any equivalent.